# How to add a checkbox in final step to lauch a exe in VS2010 setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, customization, setup-project

Currently, I'm following the steps [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx) to add a checkbox in the final step, but it seems that the checkbox still exits when I do the uninstallation. Does anybody know why or how to do a changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [control conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368035%28VS.85%29.aspx) to hide the checkbox during uninstall. For example, you can hide it when:

```
REMOVE = "ALL"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have add condition for your checkbox, look at [ControlCondition Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368035.aspx). The script from your link adds CheckBox control to Finish dialog, and you have to add the following row to ControlCondition table:

```
Dialog_ = FinishedForm
Control_ = CheckboxLaunch
Action = Hide
Condition = NOT Installed
```

To do it add the following code to the script:

```
WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlCondition table...");
sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlCondition` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Action`, `Condition`)" VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'Hide', 'NOT Installed')";
view = database.OpenView(sql);
view.Execute();
view.Close();
```

Substitute `FinishedForm` and `CheckboxLaunch` with the values you use.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey's answer works except the condition should be 'Installed', not 'NOT Installed'. Also, there is a superfluous double quote in the sql INSERT statement. So the working answer should be:

```
    WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlCondition table...");
sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlCondition` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Action`, `Condition`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'Hide', 'Installed')";
view = database.OpenView(sql);
view.Execute();
view.Close();
```