# Run application after finish installing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, installation

I attach a EXE application in Application Folder in Setup project. I create a custom action in Commit and point to this EXE to run this application when installing. But I get a problem: application will be invoked but setup will not complete until you close application.

Please help me how to run application without closing application and setup still finishes. Thanks.

I am using Visual studio 2010 Ultimate to create setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to start your application when installation is complete, after `InstallFinalize` action.

Follow the steps outlined in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/mailbag-how-can-i-customize-an-msi-in-the-visual-studio-setupdeployment-project) on customizing Visual Studio setup project. Then you will add more customization [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520711/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-final-step-to-lauch-a-exe-in-vs2010-setup-project/5541879#5541879) to remove the checkbox on uninstall.

---

Alternatively you can use [WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) to create the setup package. To launch application at the end, follow instructions in [Well Done](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/well-done/) section of the WiX Tutorial.

Comment: link doesnt work

Comment: @MoonLight Over the 11 years, the links have changed. I've updated the links.