# Running application after install was finished

Tags: installation, setup-project

I prepared an MSI project of my app and added a custom action in the commit stage to run the exe of the app after finishing the install. After finishing the setup , it try to run the exe by it failed . I debugged the problem , it was because the execute directory is system32 and not the setup folder . if I run the exe normally from the setup folder , it run normally.

Any suggestion what is the cause.

Thanks
Wasim ...

Comment: What tool do you use to create your setup?

Comment: I updated my answer with steps for Visual Studio Setup Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch the installed application after installation completes, you should do it after `InstallFinalize` action. Look at [WiX tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson8.php#8.6) to see how to add this feature.

**Update:** To add checkbox to the Completion page and run the installed application, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520711/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-final-step-to-lauch-a-exe-in-vs2010-setup-project). There's a link to [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx) which describes how to do it with a script to do it. Then you will have to add the condition, the steps can be found in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520711/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-final-step-to-lauch-a-exe-in-vs2010-setup-project/5541879#5541879) there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [type 34 custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (EXE with working directory).