# Run two executable after Installation is complete

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, executable, setup-project

I am making an Installer using VS Setup project(using VS 2010). Everything is fine except that when I am trying to run two executable file in "Committed" event of the installer they are running before Finish/Close button of Installer is clicked.

I want these executable files to run after I have clicked Close/Finish button of the installer. i.e. whole installation is completed.

Is there any way to accomplish this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I don't know, but I'd guess the button text changes to "Finish" and the window closes after pressing it because the installer has reached the end of the action sequence.

Comment: @Simon Richter: thats my problem since Finish means installer has done installation, So i want to run the executable of my application that is being installed. but Custom action doesn't allow me to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. Commit actions run as part of InstallExecuteSequence, so before the finish dialog is displayed.

If you want to execute an action when pressing Finish, you need to use control events:

- modify your MSI so the custom actions are not used by [InstallUISequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369543%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500%28VS.85%29.aspx) tables
- for the Finish button create a published [DoAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368322%28VS.85%29.aspx) [control event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368037%28VS.85%29.aspx) for each custom action

This is not supported by Visual Studio. So you can either try modifying your generated MSI with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) or use another setup authoring tool which supports it.

Comment: is there no way I can do the same using Visual studio, because I will require to edit my MSI again and again whenever the application is built . isnt it ???

Comment: No, Visual Studio doesn't support this. Yes, you will have to modify the MSI each time. If you don't want to use another setup authoring tool, you should just leave them as commit.

Comment: @Sumit You can create a script which will modify the MSI database in an automated way. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520711/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-final-step-to-lauch-a-exe-in-vs2010-setup-project) for pointers on how to do it.